# Material UI Select Grouping MenuItem - Value does not hold

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, menuitem

My Material UI React code needs to group MenuItem in Select. Yet this is not working. Default value does not get selected. Below is my example code. When I remove the the div tag, things work. For hours today I searched for a solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

export default function GroupedSelect() {
  let array=[1,2,3,4];

  return (
    <div>
        <Select  id="grouped-select" value={4}>
        {array.map(item => (
          <div>
            <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
          </div>
        ))}
        </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I remembered that I can use JavaScript to assemble JSX. That did it.